# How to plot months of multiple years of a variable

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

hey i have the following dataset

[Columns of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXgWg.png)

i already converted the orderdate column into a datetime column

now i want to plot the sales per month of each year showing month on x axis and sales on Y

```
df_grouped = df_clean.groupby(by = "ORDERDATE").sum()
```

how can i achive to just pull out data from each month in a specific year ?

thanks for helping out!

Comment: You may get an error because there is no data presented, but try the following. `df_clean.groupby([df_clear['ORDERDATE'].year, df_clear['ORDERDATE'].month]).sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two additional columns from `ORDERDATE`, which are `year` and `month` by:

```
df_clean['year'] = df_clear['ORDERDATE'].dt.year
df_clean['month'] = df_clear['ORDERDATE'].dt.month
```

And then you can filter and group by these columns.

For example:

```
df_2022 = df_clean.loc[df_clean['year'] == '2022', :]
df_2022.groupby('month').sum()
```